# Redirection to 404 Static Multilanguage pages with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, multilingual

I have an issue with a multilanguage project.

I should redirect user to static 404.html pages regarding the current locale in the url.

> www.example.com/en/foo/randomfile.html -> www.example.com/en/404.html
>   www.example.com/it/foo/randomfile.html -> www.example.com/it/404.html

I found the **ErrorDocument** directive of htaccess but I need to know the best practice to contextualize the locale.

I don't realy know the RewriteEngine so may be the answer is obvious